# How can I undo an entire command (e.g. d4b), including the motions?

Tags: cursor-movement, normal-mode, undo-redo

Say I do `d4b`, then realize I only needed `d3b`. If I hit `u`, it'll only undo the `d` part, and I'll still be 4 words back as if I just did `4b`. I'd like to end up exactly where I was before I executed `d4b`.

Is there a way to make `u` include the movements, or is there a better way to undo the entire command?

Comment: Posting this as a comment not an answer but i think the general solution to this sort of problem is constructing commands based on the granularity you need to repeat/undo. So here, instead of d4b you might just db then use the dot command to repeat. You could then do count dot (ie 3.) to delete 3 words (in addition to the word you deleted with db). Or you might choose to just delete them one at a time with dot, and ctrl-r if you delete too many. Etc.

Answer (score 4):

You're slightly misunderstanding what Vim is doing here. When you do `d4b`, there is only a *single* action, which deletes from the current position to the position where `4b` would jump to.

The behaviour that you see when you undo with `u` is *not* that Vim is undoing the `d` but leaving the `4b` motion intact. What's actually happening is that when Vim performs an undo, it places the cursor at the *beginning* of the change that is undone.

(If you do `d4wu`, you will see that the cursor stays the same location throughout: it does not end up at the end of the motion, as your interpretation would suggest.)

If you're writing a script/function [there are workarounds you can use to move the cursor back to its location prior to the undo](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Restore_the_cursor_position_after_undoing_text_change_made_by_a_script), but unfortunately, there's no general command that can always do this: it requires you to know *before* you make the edit that you're going to want the cursor position restored after an undo.

Unless you are lucky and find that the location happens to already be saved in an automatic mark as the result of another action (see `:help mark-motions`), I'm afraid it's not possible to restore the location of the cursor in the way you desire.

Answer (score 1):

If you do the same thing via visual mode: `v3bd`, then `u`, you can jump back to where you started by using the mark `` `> `` (that's backtick).

Look up `:h marks` to learn more; `>` corresponds to the end of visual selection, backtick means you want specific position, and not the beginning of line.