# Restoring cursor to position before delete after Undo

Tags: cut-copy-paste, cursor-movement, cursor

This question is asked multiple places but none have an answer that works for me. I've tried:
``` '' `` g; g, ; , Ctrl+o ```

In a file add:

```
123456789
```

Move your cursor over `7` in normal mode, type `d4h`, press `u`. You're back where you started but the cursor is on `3` now.

You can type `4l` for this case to end up back where you were but what about more complex deletions.

Comment: for more complex deletions, set the mark first, then later go to that mark.

Comment: If you already have a solution for your simple example, why don't you give an example of what you mean by "more complex deletions"?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible.  When vim performs an undo, the cursor is left at the start of the change that is undone.

[Here's an answer to a similar question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/13415/1643) which explains this.

Answer (score 0):

Using lua api (nvim) we can do:

```
line, col = unpack(vim.api.nvim_win_get_cursor(0))
vim.cmd [[ normal 4X]]
vim.cmd [[ normal u]]
vim.api.nvim_win_set_cursor({0}, {line , col})
```

The first line saves line and column, the second line erases 4 chars, the third one gets back one action and the last one restores the line and cursor positions.

Your question helped me improve a function called "preserve":

```lua
function _G.preserve(cmd)
    local cmd = string.format('keepjumps keeppatterns execute %q', cmd)
    local line, col = unpack(vim.api.nvim_win_get_cursor(0))
    vim.api.nvim_command(cmd)
    local lastline = vim.fn.line('$')
    if line > lastline then
        line = lastline
    end
    vim.api.nvim_win_set_cursor({0}, {line , col})
end
```

The function `win_get_cursor` gives us more precise information. you could also create marks like [@maxim-kim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/9333/maxim-kim) suggested.

As we can use this function to squeeze blank lines we are using an if statement to ensure the line will neve be beond the buffer last line.

Here a function to squeeze blank lines using the above function, in this case I placed the function at `~/.config/nvim/lua/tools.lua`

```lua
local M = {}

M.squeeze_blank_lines = function()
    -- references: https://vi.stackexchange.com/posts/26304/revisions
    local old_query = vim.fn.getreg('/')    -- save search register
    preserve('sil! 1,.s/^\\n\\{2,}/\\r/gn') -- set current search count number
    local result = vim.fn.searchcount({maxcount = 1000, timeout = 500}).current
    local line, col = unpack(vim.api.nvim_win_get_cursor(0))
    preserve('sil! keepp keepj %s/^\\n\\{2,}/\\r/ge')
    preserve('sil! keepp keepj %s/\\v($\\n\\s*)+%$/\\r/e')
    if result > 0 then
        vim.api.nvim_win_set_cursor({0}, {(line - result), col})
    end
    vim.fn.setreg('/', old_query)           -- restore search register
end

return M
```

Some more features that make use of the "preserve"

```lua
vim.cmd([[cnoreab cls Cls]])
vim.cmd([[command! Cls lua preserve('%s/\\s\\+$//ge')]])
vim.cmd([[command! Reindent lua preserve("sil keepj normal! gg=G")]])
```

Now you can use `cls` to remove trailing spaces, `Reindent`, and many other things you came up with.

```lua
-- keep cursor position when joinig lines
-- undo keeps cursor position (at least line)
local opts = { noremap=true, silent=true }

buf_set_keymap('n', 'J', ':lua preserve(":join")<cr>', opts)
buf_set_keymap('n', 'u', ':lua preserve(":undo")<cr>', opts)
buf_set_keymap('n', '<c-s>', [[:lua preserve("%s/\\s\\+$//ge")<cr>]])
```

With all these things your macros could become horrible, so I have an alias to open vim with not plugins or autocommands:

```
alias vinone="nvim -u NONE -U NONE -N -i NONE -c 'nnoremap <Space> /'"
```

I am mentioning this because sometimes we fix one thing and cause other problems. Read also about `noautocmd`

```
:sil! argdo :noautocmd norm! @a
```